# Filter on value in another row

Tags: select, group-by, firebird

Please see image of the data and my code so far.

In this example I only want the first two rows to be retrieved. The reason for this is because where JobID is 1684 the sum of STILL_REQUIRED is > 0

Where JOBID is 1683 the sum of STILL_REQUIRED is 0, so don't show this row.

I think I need to get the sum when it is grouped by JobID, but I cant get it working. I am using Firebird.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ID, 
             JobID, 
             NAME, 
             ORDERNUM, 
             STARTAFTER, 
             FINISHBEFORE, 
             START_OFFSET_MINS, 
             TOTAL_MINUTES_REQ - 
             (SELECT COALESCE(
                       SUM(TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.END_TIME - 
                           TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_TIME) / 60, 0) 
                FROM TABLE_PROCESSTIMES 
               WHERE TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.PROCESSID = TABLE_PROCESSES.ID 
                  AND TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_DATE <= '24.04.2018'
             ) AS STILL_REQUIRED 
FROM TABLE_PROCESSES) 
WHERE STILL_REQUIRED > 0
```

Comment: It works but it needs to go a step futher.. it should show all the rows for each job, where the sum of still_required for that jobid  is >0. So it should only show two rows with jobid 1684 because the sum of jobid 1684 still_required is 60+0 which is >0.   thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output as text.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my understanding of your needs, you could use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to achieve this. Define your main query within the CTE and then do a `JOIN` on a second `SELECT` which calculates the total per `JobID`:

```
WITH results AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
           JobID, 
           NAME, 
           ORDERNUM, 
           STARTAFTER, 
           FINISHBEFORE, 
           START_OFFSET_MINS, 
           TOTAL_MINUTES_REQ - 
           (SELECT COALESCE(
                     SUM(TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.END_TIME - 
                         TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_TIME) / 60, 0) 
              FROM TABLE_PROCESSTIMES 
             WHERE TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.PROCESSID = TABLE_PROCESSES.ID 
               AND TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_DATE <= '24.04.2018'
           ) AS STILL_REQUIRED 
      FROM TABLE_PROCESSES
)
SELECT x.*
  FROM results x
  JOIN (SELECT JobID, SUM(STILL_REQUIRED) AS STILL_REQUIRED
          FROM results
      GROUP BY JobID) y
    ON x.JobID = y.JobID
 WHERE y.STILL_REQUIRED > 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much - works perfectly!! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. If this resolved your issue, please be sure to mark your question as answered. :)

Comment: I cant find anywhere to mark the question as answered??

Comment: There should be a tick mark underneath the answer - if you click it, it will go green to indicate that an answer was correct.